# Why are extra columns being generated for my entities that participate in a M:M relationship?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, many-to-many, ef-code-first

I have the following entities:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

And the following code in `MyContext.OnModelCreating`:

```
mb.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
mb.Entity<T>().ToTable("Users", "myschema");
mb.Entity<T>().ToTable("Roles", "myschema");
mb.Entity<User>().HasMany(x => x.Roles).WithMany().Map(a => a.ToTable("UsersRoles", "myschema"));
mb.Entity<Role>().HasMany(x => x.Permissions).WithMany().Map(a => a.ToTable("RolesPermissions", "myschema"));
```

All other conventions are the default ones. During database initialization, the **Users** table has a foreign key column **Role_Id**. *This does not make sense*. The **Users**, **Roles**, and **UsersRoles** tables are otherwise correct.

While using EF, the **User.Role_Id** is always *NULL* and transactions succeed, and **UsersRoles** is updated as expected. If I delete the column, EF fails complaining about it.

Why is EF doing this and how can I fix it -- preferably removing the unnecessary column?

Comment: On a completely unrelated note, database tables are generally named in singular form rather than plural (i.e. `User` and `Role` rather than `Users` and `Roles`).

Comment: @DJKRAZE: No, it's simply a database design idiom; it doesn't have anything to do with EF (hence why I said it was completely unrelated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This mapping is wrong:

```
mb.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(x => x.Roles)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(a => a.ToTable("UsersRoles", "myschema"));
```

It must be:

```
mb.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(x => x.Roles)
    .WithMany(x => x.Users)
    .Map(a => a.ToTable("UsersRoles", "myschema"));
```

Your first mapping tells EF that you have a many-to-many relationship without exposed navigation property in `Role`. Therefore EF assumes that `Role.Users` belongs to another - by default one-to-many - relationship between `User` and `Role` which has an end in `User`, also not being exposed in the model. The FK column you see belongs to this second association.